# Sql Column Grouping

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

I have a table called `SkillSets` with a `SkillID` field and a `SkillSetID` field. Let's says I have records in this table as in:

```
SkillID  SkillSetID
-------  ----------
750      2
750      4
750      5
751      3
751      4
751      6
```

I need a query that produces the following:

```
SkillID  SkillSetIDs
-------  ----------
750      2,4,5
751      3,4,6
```

Seems to me I remember seeing this using some sort of xml clause but cant find anything about it, and just don't know how to get it done without using a cursor or while loop. Can you help?

Comment: You need to do a string concatenation aggregation operation.  This is highly database specific.  Which engine are you using?

Comment: If you're using TSQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2. So, nothing rings a bell using some sort of XML clause? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this would work:

```
SELECT SkillID, GROUP_CONCAT(SkillSetID) As SkillSetIDs
FROM skills
GROUP BY SkillID
```

But `GROUP_CONCAT` is MySQL specific, so if you are using a different database, that won't fly.

Answer (score 0):

does this help you out?

```
select 'test' as Test, 1 as Item 
into #test 
union select 'test2', 2 
union select 'test', 3 
union select NUll, 4 
union select 'test', 5 

select t2.test, STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + cast(t1.Item as varchar (10) )
        FROM #test t1 where t2.test = t1.test 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
     from #test t2
     group by t2.test
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

[**SQLFIDDLEExample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f04a/9)

```
SELECT
s.SkillID,
STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + SkillSetID
        FROM SkillSets s2
        WHERE s2.SkillID = s.SkillID
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '')  AS SkillSetIDs
FROM SkillSets s
GROUP BY s.SkillID
```

Result:

```
| SKILLID | SKILLSETIDS |
-------------------------
|     750 |       2,4,5 |
|     751 |       3,4,6 |
```